# Как сделать список запрещённых символов

Tags: python, aiogram

Возник вопрос, как можно сделать список запрещённых символов, в сообщений пользователя? Я знаю как сделать запрет на символы, но хотелось бы узнать как можно будет оптимизировать. Мой вариант:

```py
elif '@' in message.text or '/' in message.text or '*' in message.text or '#' in message.text or '!' in message.text or '$' in message.text or '%' in message.text or '^' in message.text or '?' in message.text or '/' in message.text or '[' in message.text or ']' in message.text or '-' in message.text or '_' in message.text or ')' in message.text or '+' in message.text or '=' in message.text or ';' in message.text or '`' in message.text or '~' in message.text or '.' in message.text or ',' in message.text or '<' in message.text or '>' in message.text or "'" in message.text or '"' in message.text or '|' in message.text or ';' in message.text or ';' in message.text:
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы вели запрещенный символ")
```

Comment: А открывающую круглую скобку можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
for i in message.text:
    if i in '''@/*#!$%^?\[]-_)+=;`~.,<>'"|''': 
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы ввели запрещенный символ")
```

Comment: Хм понял задумку, теперь вопрос. Если я его вынесу в settings.py, он сможет так-же по задумке вашей работать?

Comment: Ну да... Если то, что в вопросе уже было в этом файле.

Comment: Благодарю, за ответ!

Comment: Поставьте галочку ;)

Answer (score 0):

Не надо проверять посимвольно - это медленно. Превратите сообщение в `set` и пересеките с запрещёнными символами:

```
prohibited = set('@/*#!$%^?\[]-_)+=;`~.,<>\'"|')

if set(message.text) & prohibited:
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы ввели запрещенный символ")
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!